# How to make 2 websites speak to each other

Tags: web-development

The company I work for has two websites. Website-1 is the public website with a product catalogue and Website-2 is a secure website (requires login) where our customers can buy products. The problem is Website-1 and Website-2 don't exchange information. For example, there can be a personalized offer on Website-1 for a customer but they're required to login two Website-2 to buy the product. However, when they login to Website-2 the customer is required to navigate the website to find this product. This is a bad customer experience and our customers can't find the product. When the customer logs in to Website-2 I would like a Call To Action to pop-up immediately so they can buy the product and there's no navigation. How do I explain this in technical terms to the developer team? - that Website-1 needs to send info to Website-2

Comment: Why are there two separate websites at all?   I don't know of any other eCommerce site that does that.   Amazon certainly has functionality to purchase right in their catalog pages.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller it's an investment website. First website is for new customers and the second website is for existing customers. Website-1 can also be used for personalized marketing to existing customers.

Comment: I don't know of any other websites that divide their content for new users and existing users.

Comment: Strategically, combining the websites and just displaying conditional content for the different user types would probably work best in the long run. In the short term, it really depends on your CMSs as to what you can and can't do. Look into documentation on your Website-2 and see whether you can pass it a redirect on the login screen, so as soon as the user logs in, they automatically redirect to the desired product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since people are commenting on your question and you seems to have your concerns to maintain two different sites. Thus, I will try to answer your question which you have asked.

On the contrary, I do believe its not worth to maintain this favoritism for new and old customers. Instead having a reliable portal for both would be an ideal solution. Thus, saving you server/development/maintenance cost and giving you leverage to work on new cool/requested feature.

**Solution to your concern Issue :-)**

1) You can have a single/common Database, thus both sites have consistent and up-to-date data. Eg: If a last item of particular product is just bought on on Website-1, then it should not be remain listed for sale on Website-2.
-- In simple words, better to have a common Backend for two different Frontend Application. Almost all the web applications (who also have a mobile application) follow similar regards. Such as; facebook/twitter both posses same database/backend server but for the clients it variates, some use online in web browser and others on their mobile devices.

2) Your requirement of passing parameter of Website-1 to Website-2 can easily be handled with custom rich URLS. Lets take the url of this question of yours `https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118504/how-to-make-2-websites-speak-to-each-other`. 
**First part**: says navigate to webmaster.stackexchange.com
**Second and Third part**: says that its a question with an identifier 118504
**Fourth part**: is a short compressed text of your provided title to maintain good SEO.

> Similarly, you could have `**Buy Now Button**` or `**Proceed to Payment**` on your Website-1 Product, which should be redirecting to some url like this **`www.website-2.com/shirt/123456/blue/small/newyearsale`**. So when you navigate to this URL you can easily interpret this URL with your controller on Website-2 and can understand that this user is being redirected from Website-1 and would like to purchase **Blue Small sized Shirt with ID: 123456 available on discount for NewYear**.

Since, now you know why user landed to your site; you should now show Button to `**PAY HERE**` or `**CONFIRM YOUR ORDER**` and proceed with the transaction on your secured Website-2.

Hope this helps. Cheer!

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, Good Sir. Most financial services eg, banks,investment funds separate their new customers and existing customers - due to KYC. Hence, in this scenario Website-2 is a secure login platform for customers who have been KYCd and which enables them to utilize account origination processes. That being said, it's not a matter of new or old customers. It's based on the customer shape of KYC i.e. New (not KYCd) and Existing (KYCd).

Comment: Thank you for expressing your concern and explaining its need. With a simple Google search I was able to understand this concept of KYC (Know-Your-Customer) in Financial Services `I learned something new today :-)`. 

For other who might land here later; Take this instance as Website-1 with BOT Crawling enabled for SEO, so that the world can know about their existence and the Website-2 for more sophisticated flows such as purchasing/contractual services behind the secure regulations. Cheers!